# Display error message if there's no internet connection

Tags: microsoft-metro

I have a Metro app done using C# & XAML. I'm using the WebView control to load a URL, and also using Notifications to update the tiles. If the machine isn't connected to the internet, the tile, and the webview are blank. I want to be display some sort of a message indicating that the app isn't able to connect to the Internet.

How do I check for Internet connection? In a `try catch` block or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Network Information sample?  It shows how to check for internet connectivity from inside your app.  Short version...

```
var connectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

switch (connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel())
                {
                    case NetworkConnectivityLevel.None:
                        connectionProfileInfo += "Connectivity Level : None\n";
                        break;
                    case NetworkConnectivityLevel.LocalAccess:
                        connectionProfileInfo += "Connectivity Level : Local Access\n";
                        break;
                    case NetworkConnectivityLevel.ConstrainedInternetAccess:
                        connectionProfileInfo += "Connectivity Level : Constrained Internet Access\n";
                        break;
                    case NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess:
                        connectionProfileInfo += "Connectivity Level : Internet Access\n";
                        break;
                }
```

Make a check before trying to use the WebView and prompt the user accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I'll lookup the Network sample as well.