# Check internet connection and stop execution in WinJS

Tags: winjs

If my application needs internet connection from the start. How can I prevent the execution after I find no internet?

I know how to check. But I need help in stopping for further execution.

Answer (score 2):

```
var internetconection = new Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile();
        if ((!('getNetworkConnectivityLevel' in internetconection)) || ((internetconection.getNetworkConnectivityLevel()) < 3)) {
            alert("internet not connected");
        }
else{
    alert("internet connected");
}
```

Try this,
Refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564389/Check-connection-with-WinJS

Answer (score 0):

You may have added (or borrowed code from the MSDN samples as I often do) that uses a event listener for onNetworkStatusChange event. Try removing that with removeEventListener to stop further checks for internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check de connection like this post answer:
This is for c#, but the same classes is available for javascrip

[Display error message if there's no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901513/display-error-message-if-theres-no-internet-connection)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile